# Save two related entities with typeorm in postgres

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I need to store 2 records which relates to each other.
Table1 has relation to Table2 and at the same time Table2 has relation to Table1

The code of creation and storing records:

```
    const account = this.accountRepository.create({ 
      // ...
    });
    const user = this.authUserRepository.create({
      account,
      // ...
    });

    account.primary_user = user;

    await Promise.all([
      this.accountRepository.save(account),
      this.authUserRepository.save(user),
    ]);
```

Thats how entities look like:

```
// auth-user.entity.ts
@Entity({ name: 'auth_user' })
export class AuthUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  public id: number;
  
  @OneToOne(() => Account, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'account_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  public account: Account;
}

// account.entity.ts
@Entity({ name: 'account' })
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  public id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => AuthUser, {
    nullable: true,
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'primary_user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  public primary_user: AuthUser;
}
```

In DB I see that no any of related ids are filled: `account.primary_user_id` is null and `auth_user.account_id` is null

*PS: I am not the person who designed this DB structure I must follow it*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the Promise.all() is working for your first two calls, I would try this instead just to be sure:

```js
const [account, user] = Promise.all([
  await this.accountRepository.create({ // ... })
  await this.authUserRepository.create({ // ... })
]);

account.primary_user = user;

await this.accountRepository.save(account);
```

You could also change you cascading options to work on `insert` and `update` so you could do:

```js
const account = {
  ...
  user: {}
}
await this.accountRepository.save(account);
// save will create if item not found with id
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This approach works, but we need to save the same record twice

    const account = this.accountRepository.create({});
    const user = this.authUserRepository.create({  account });

    account.primary_user = user;

    await  this.accountRepository.save(account);
    await Promise.all([
      this.accountRepository.save(account),
      this.authUserRepository.save(user),
    ]);

Comment: You could do `.save(account)` twice then, but I really don't see why you need to duplicate the data.